# how to match webview width and height with content(gif file here)

Tags: android, webview, gif

i'm trying to show gif files in web view and create a nine patch photo(as frame)around the web view.but always web view and it's frame gets fill parent width.but i need the frame exactly shows around gif file without any extra space,this is my code:

```
  <FrameLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:foreground="@drawable/frame_tir3"
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <WebView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/web1"/>
  </FrameLayout>
```

and i tried very different codes but any doen't work.